# View animation sometimes perform in zero time

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

Sometimes animation perform without animation effect(zero time).
In below code sometimes code print "Time = 0.0000002"

```
let date = Date()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

}) { (finish) in
    print("Time = \(Date().timeIntervalSince(date))")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will because you are not animating anything inside the `animations` block so this is a normal behavior. You can verify with below code,

```
 let date = Date()
 self.view.layer.opacity = 0.5
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations:            
    self.view.layer.opacity = 1.0
 }) { (finish) in
      print("Time = \(Date().timeIntervalSince(date))")
 }
```

The purpose of `animations` block is to animate the property's start and end values difference on the given time. Once the property value is reached to the given value in `animations` block it will immediately call `finish` block.

If you have nothing to animate and just want a callback after few seconds better to use `Timer` or `DispatchQueue` e.g,

```
Timer(timeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false) { timer in
    // Do whatever you want
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
   // Do whatever you want
}
```